# Is there a way to change (or set) the True North in Expo-Location?

Tags: javascript, react-native, location, expo

I am working on an expo react-native project, in which I am trying to set a compass pointed to a different fixed location (instead of true north). Any tips on how I can achieve this?

Is there a way to change the "true north" to a custom one (giving a latitude and longitude)? Or a way in which I can set a custom location using latitude and longitude, following which I can have my compass pointed to that lat & long which constantly updates (such as that used by `Location.watchPositionAsync`)?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! I have noticed that no one else has asked this question, so I hope that the solution can help others too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your location
Then calculate the angle to the desired latitude and then point to the angle

Here is a formula for calculating the angle between two points

```
function angleFromCoordinate(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
    var p1 = {
        x: lat1,
        y: lon1
    };

    var p2 = {
        x: lat2,
        y: lon2
    };
    // angle in radians
    var angleRadians = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
    // angle in degrees
    var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
    console.log(angleDeg);
    return angleDeg;
}
```